# Saving $_SESSION['MM_adUser'] in MySQL

Tags: php

I built a site in Dreamweaver a while ago and have revamped it to 'version 2'
I managed to get user log-in to authenticate with Active Directory and have added $_SESSION['MM_adUser'] for their full AD name.

This seems to work fine as adding:

```
<?php $_SESSION['MM_adUser']; ?>
```

to the page, shows the users full name in the browser .. ie: John Smith

However, i now want to insert this into MySQL, so i added to the bottom of the page (with some other misc variables):

```
<input name="SavedBy" type="hidden" value=<?php $_SESSION['MM_adUser']; ?> />
```

but it only inserts the users first name! Removing type="hidden" does indeed show it on the page as only their first name.

Question is, why the change? Why is it losing the last name? 
I'm guessing it has something to do with whitespace as this came up in an error when trying various fixes, but, alas, i can't fix it :(

Any ideas, please?

Comment: `value="<?php echo $_SESSION['MM_adUser']; ?>" />`

Comment: you're generating `value=John Doe`. without the quotes, only `John` becomes part of the actual value, and `Doe` becomes some unknown dangling tag attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note the `echo`

```
value="<?php echo $_SESSION['MM_adUser']; ?>" />
```

Comment: Indeed, I had echo in my code actually but didnt include it here for some reason! Adding the quotes around it did the trick - thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps putting quotes around your value would help?

```
<input name="SavedBy" type="hidden" value="<?= $_SESSION['MM_adUser']; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Although all awnsers are ofcourse correct. You mentioned you want to store this in mysql? Then there is no need to put it in a hidden input field first. You can just use `$_SESSION['MM_adUser']` in your mysql query. I guess now you are using `$_POST['SavedBy']`?

Putting a "SavedBy" in a hidden input field is never a good idea. I'm free to alter it So even if "John Smith" is logged in, I can still send in "Hugo Delsing"

Comment: Putting $_SESSION['MM_adUser'] in the mysql query didnt work.